# how to disable and enable SSIS package using commandline?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, command-line

I have a scenario where SSIS packages are deployed at the customer's site and they have some data issues.

Because of this we are developing new packages to fix the corrupted data.

When my new pacakge will be executed I want to disable the previous packages for the time when the fix is running on and then enable it again.

Are there any commands or scripts which I can execute from my new package to disable other packages and then enable them back afterwards?

Comment: How do you schedule and run the packages?  SQL Server Agent? Some other scheduling tool? From some client?

Comment: To disable an entire package, you don't run it. To enable it, you run it.

Comment: we schedule it using job and i used "Execute sql script" task to disable and enable the job. thanks for your comments @RLF